# Error trying call method from view Thymeleaf Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a problem when im try to call a method from view.

My Java class with methods

```
public class FuncionesMuestroteca {
    @Bean
    public static boolean estoyMuestroteca() {
        boolean resultado = false;

        return resultado;
    }
}
```

Now i call function from header.html

```
<th:block th:text="${FuncionesMuestroteca.estoyMuestroteca()}"/>
```

In POM.xml i have imported thymeleaf-extras version 2.1.0.RELEASE and thymeleaf 2.1.5

```
<groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
<artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
```

And here the StackTrace

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method estoyMuestroteca() on null context object
```

If you need anything else, do not hesitate to tell me and I'll put it. Thank you in advance.

new StackTrace:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'estoyMuestroteca' available
```

HTML Edit

```
<div th:text="${@estoyMuestroteca.estoyMuestroteca()}"></div>
```

Method actual

```
@Configuration
public class FuncionesMuestroteca {
    @Bean(name = "estoyMuestroteca")
    public boolean estoyMuestroteca() {
        boolean resultado = false;

        return resultado;
    }
}
```

[I add an image of the folder structure of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amzWb.jpg)

Comment: delete static in `public static boolean estoyMuestroteca()` and add `@Configuration`  on `public class FuncionesMuestroteca `

Comment: To have direct access to spring beans use `@`. For example: `<div th:text="${@urlService.getApplicationUrl()}">...</div>` you can find it documented at point 5 at [docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html)

Comment: Thank you very very much Patrick, I have made the changes that you have told me, but now the error is "No bean named 'estoyMuestroteca' available". Is it possible that I have to configure or add the bean in a controller?

Comment: can you add the stacktrace please

Comment: Sorry bro, i put in new answer cause is too long for a comment

Comment: can you also show your changed html and `estoyMuestroteca()` method

Comment: I'm sorry, I just added it

Comment: try to use it this way: `<div th:text="${@funcionesMuestroteca.estoyMuestroteca()}"></div>`

Comment: So should I change the Bean's name or delete it?

Comment: now the error is No bean named 'funcionesMuestroteca' available

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A couple things here.  First, the static method:

```
public class FuncionesMuestrotecaUtilidad { //note name change

    public static boolean estoyMuestroteca() {
         return false; //don't need to create extra variables if this is what you need
    }
}
```

In your HTML, you can use the proper syntax for calling a static method:

```
<th:block th:text="${T(com.package.FuncionesMuestrotecaUtilidad).estoyMuestroteca()}">
<!-- do whatever -->
</th:block>
```

Replace `com.package` with your package name.  Also, this does not need the `@Bean` or `@Configuration` annotation - you are just calling a static method directly.

The major caveat to all this is that there might be a better way to design the code without using static methods.  But that is outside the scope of this question.

Lastly, it makes a lot of sense to move to a newer version of Thymeleaf.  It's far faster, less restrictive, and has more features.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has solved my problem. But I would like to follow your recommendations. I am trying to change the version of thymeleaf

Comment: @bphilipnyc what is the way to call a non-static function from a template?

Comment: Not really the way you want to go.  You want to have your controller add the variable to the model and have Thymeleaf (or whatever framework you're using) simply display the value.  This keeps your view far simpler.  Take a look at the Thymeleaf docs and you'll see that this is the general idea.

Comment: A major strength of Thymeleaf is simply passing on the HTML template to a UI person (someone who doesn't necessarily need to know a thing about Java).  So keeping complex logic out of it will save you lots of trouble.

Comment: What does T stands for @vphilipnyc ? in the function

Comment: Type.  Common usage in Java

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to call a method that includes parameters from the view:
1: Create an interface have method that includes parameters(If the method not includes parameter, remove the parameters in example function):

```
public interface RewriteUrl {
    String rewriteUrl(String name, Integer id);
}
```

2: In beans's configuration file, add new bean implement that interface, as follows:

```
@Bean(name = "rewriteSongUrl")
    public RewriteUrl rewriteSongUrl() {
        return (String name, Integer id) -> {
            String url = name + "." + id + ".html";
            return getRewriteUrl(url);
        };
    }
```

3: In view, call bean:

```
<a th:href="${@rewriteSongUrl.rewriteUrl(singer.name, singer.id)}"></a>
```