# Spring Thymeleaf - Call Service Method Boolean for Display of HTML Item

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

In my Header HTML I display a UL/LI Menu where the visiblity of one of the LI items depends on a Service method call.

I tried this:

**HomeController**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @Autowired 
    private EtdService etdService;

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home(Model model) throws EtdException {

        model.addAttribute("tierTemplate", etdService.getTierTemplate());  
        // Also tried this explicitly
        model.addAttribute("etdService", etdService);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**Service Interface (EtdService)**

```
public interface EtdService {
  boolean isChangeUserAllowed();
}
```

**Service Implementation (EtdServiceImpl)**

```
@Component
public class EtdServiceImpl implements EtdService {

    @Override
    public boolean isChangeUserAllowed() {
        System.out.println("Got here");
        return false;
    }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<li th:if="${@etdService.isChangeUserAllowed()}" class="nav-item dropdown" id="changeUserPanel" role="presentation">
<!-- ... Definition of this LI -- note can't put a new DIV in a UL list ... -->
</li>
```

**Error:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'etdService' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1221) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing an instance method in Thymeleaf.  Here are two options:

1) Reference it by adding the value of the boolean to the model:

```
@GetMapping("/home")
public String home(Model model) throws EtdException {

   //...
   model.addAttribute("isChangeUserAllowed", etdService.isChangeUserAllowed());
   return "home";
}
```

And in your HTML: `th:if="${isChangeUserAllowed}"`

To avoid NPEs, you can alternatively use `#bools.isTrue(isChangeUserAllowed)` or the appropriate method in the `bools` utility.

This is the preferred way and the path that the Thymeleaf documentation takes.  A clear benefit is that the front-end is now not tied to the service.

2) Reference it statically instead (not recommended):

[Error trying call method from view Thymeleaf Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402821/error-trying-call-method-from-view-thymeleaf-spring)

---

Aside: the recommended way is to use constructor injection instead of autowiring.

Comment: Thanks, working; also, can I avoid having every method and every Controller set this? (short of inheriting all controllers from a base controller). I need to set a global attribute for a Header item, regardless of which result is returned.

Comment: Offhand, the static route would do that for you, though there could be a better way.  That would, of course, mean reworking the code to support a static method.

Comment: Looks like I found a good way to globalize common Model Attr's without Static: It's to use `@ControllerAdvice` (all-controller-method intercept) and then `@ModelAttribute` on the method. Example here: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/controller-advice-with-model-attribute.html . I followed it and it's working, I'll post a reply here.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer by **bphilipnyc** (set the direct value into the model),

`model.addAttribute("isChangeUserAllowed", etdService.isChangeUserAllowed());`

If you need to globalize common Model Attributes without re-adding every time, a solution is a `@ControllerAdvice` class with a `@ModelAttribute`, e.g.

```
/**
 * This class is used to globalize common Model Attributes without re-adding every time
 * The approach is to mark it as @ControllerAdvice to make it apply to every Controller method, 
 * and implement a @ModelAttribute Model-Adder to append to the model on every Controller method.
 */

// Makes the methods of this class apply to all Controller Request methods
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalController {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @ModelAttribute   // A Model Attribute Adder method
    public void setGlobalModelAttributes(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("isChangeUserAllowed", myService.isChangeUserAllowed());
        model.addAttribute("currentUserFullName", myService.getCurrentUserFullName());

    }       
}
```

Some more examples

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33879102/1005607

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation